# Use Webpack to split out a module so that it can be loaded in a WebWorker

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I have a web app that I compile with webpack.  One of the modules that my code uses is named `table.js`.  Until recently, it's just been another module and has been compiled into my `bundle.js` file with everything else.

Now I need to run `table.js` in a Web Worker, so I need to pull it and its dependencies into a separate file that can be loaded both standalone and by my other modules.

At first I thought to include `table.js` in my `webpack.config.js`'s `entry`.

```
var config = {
    ...
    entry: {
        app: [ './src/main.js', './src/classes/table.js' ],
        vendors: [],
    },
    ...
}
```

That didn't work.  Then I thought to separate it out like my vendors bundle.

```
var config = {
    /* for vendors (and other modules) we have a CDN for */
    addExternal: function (name, globalVar) {
        this.externals[name] = globalVar;
        this.entry.vendors.push(name);
    },

    /* for vendors we don't have a CDN for */
    addVendor: function (name, path) {
        this.resolve.alias[name] = path;
        this.entry.vendors.push(name);
    },

    addPlugin: function (plugin) {
        this.plugins.push(plugin);
    },

    entry: {
        app: [ './src/main.js' ],
        vendors: [],
        table: [ __dirname + '/src/classes/table.js' ]
    },

    plugins: [],

    externals: { },

    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/public/dist/',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/dist/',
        sourceMapFile: '[file].map'
    },

    resolve: {
        alias: { 'table': './src/classes/table.js' },
        extensions: [ '', '.js', '.jsx' ]
    },
    ...
}

/* add vendors and externals */
...

config.addPlugin(new CommonsChunkPlugin('vendors', 'vendors.js'));
config.addPlugin(new CommonsChunkPlugin('table', 'table.js'));
```

This seems to pull Table and its dependencies into a chunk of `bundle.js`, `1.bundle.js`.  Unfortunately, then calling `import Table from 'table'` causes this error:

```
ERROR in CommonsChunkPlugin: While running in normal mode it's not allowed to use a non-entry chunk (table)
```

I also have a circular dependency between `TableStore` and `Table`.  `TableStore` needs to stay in `bundle.js` because it shouldn't be loaded into the Web Worker.  Previously, when I've needed to throw things into a separate chunk, I've done:

```
if (someThingNeedsRequiring) {
    require.ensure([], () => {
        require('something');
    }
}
```

With the circular dependency, this doesn't seem to work.

```
/* table.js */
let _inWebWorker = self instanceof Window,
    TableStore = null;

if (!_inWebWorker) {
    require.ensure([], function() { TableStore = require('../stores/table-store'); } );
}

/* table-store.js */
import Table from 'table';
```

Could someone set me straight on the correct way to have my `webpack.config.js` and how to use my `import`s in my module files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(It's been quite a while since I figured this out, and I haven't touched the project in nearly six months, so I may have missed some of the details.  Comment if it's not working, and I'll try to figure out what I'm missing.)

#### webpack.config

It turns out there are two handy-dandy JavaScript packages for doing what I want: `worker-loader` and `workerjs`.

```
npm install --save workerjs worker-loader
```

I added this in my webpack.config.js:

```
var config = {
    // ...

    worker: {
        output: {
            filename: '[name].worker.js',
            chunkFilename: '[name].worker.js'
        }
    },

    // ...
}
```

#### require()

In order to specify that I want my class to be run in a WebWorker file, my require looks like:

```
// ecmaScript 6
import TableWorker from 'worker?name=tableRoller!path/to/table';

// ecmaScript 5
var TableWorker = require('worker?name=tableRoller!path/to/table');
```

`TableWorker` is just a variable name I used for table.js's `export default class Table {...}`.  The `name=tableRoller` specifies the generated outputted `[name].worker.js` filename.  For example, I have another WebWorker named `distCalc.worker.js`, so my `import` looks like:

```
import DistWorker from 'worker?name=distCalc!path/to/distWorker';
```

Note that in this case, `distWorker` only ever runs in a WebWorker, while `Table` is used in both my `main.js` entry point and my `tableRoller.worker.js` WebWorker file.

`workerjs` and `worker-loader` generate a new entry point file and pull in all of the dependencies of those classes.  Tobias Koppers (worker-loader) and Eugene Ware (workerjs) are geniuses.

#### Detecting WebWorker

My `_inWebWorker` detection is:

```
let _inWebWorker = typeof Window === 'undefined';
```

Answer (score 0):

Change output **filename** in your **webpack.config.js** file

```
output: {
    path: __dirname + '/public/dist/',
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    sourceMapFile: '[file].map'
},
```

then Webpack can separate your entries with its name in dist directory.